# Getting the windows version of a "cat" command?

Tags: cat

I would like to have this script's windows version

```
cat name-of-APK.apk | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64 | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '='
```

How can I get that?

Comment: Maybe by asking in a Windows community.

Comment: @Panki Why? Windows users don't use cat.

Comment: [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/), [UUOC](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is explicitly *not* about Linux/UNIX

Comment: `Get-FileHash -Path name-of-APK.apk -Algorithm SHA256 | ForEach-Object { [Convert]::ToBase64String($_.Hash) } | %{ $_.Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').TrimEnd('=') }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like PowerShell has `cat` -command, but it's just an alias for `Get-Content`, as is `type` ([source](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-cat/)). So if you need to script Windows, I'd suggest learning PowerShell scripting.

If you want to use *NIX commands and tools in Windows, Cygwin is one option. You can also run bash shell directly in Windows. Instructions can be found over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use `cat` in PowerShell (which is an alias for `Get-Content`) or `type` in Cmd.